# In MS Excel how do we show the bar-chart like in this picture?

Tags: excel

In Excel, how do you generate a right-most cell with a bar graph ,  like this :

[image]

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=REPT("|",ROUND($C2/10,0))
```

You repeat a character *integer* times.

Comment: The ones in your picture don't look anything like conditional formatting, they're more like `|`s or `I`s, there could be virtually infinite numbers of applicable characters, you can even fool around with proper density of the last char if you have enough time to sink.